# Profile a process via its child and kill the child afterwards

Tags: c, fork, profiling, perf, execvp

I am trying to figure out a way to profile in **C** a process via its child and after a moment the parent process kills its child to stop profiling. I am using **perf** to profile my application. perf is going to output its result in a file when killed. It looks like this in a bash script :

```
./run &
perf stat -o perf.data -p <pid_run> &
kill -9 <pid_perf>
```

What I have done so far :

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <signal.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>

 static pid_t perf_id;

 void start() {
   char *filename="test_data";
   char ppid_str[24];

   pid_t pid = fork();
   if (pid == 0){

      pid_t ppid = getppid();
      sprintf(ppid_str, "%d",ppid);
      char *args[] = {"/usr/bin/perf", "stat","-p",ppid_str,"-o", filename, NULL};
      execvp(args[0], args);
   }
   else {

      perf_id = pid
   }
}

void stop() {
  kill(perf_id,SIGKILL);
}
```

I have an issue getting the output of **perf**. 
This is an example of code that could run the parent process :

```
int main() {
    start();
    int a = 0;
    a+=1;
    stop();
    // ... // There are other instructions after the stop
    return 0;
 }
```

I am not getting any output from perf when running this code. I have to kill the parent process to get an output.

If I put a sleep call before killing the child process, then the program will output an empty file.

**EDIT :**

**stat** argument is an example in my command, I want also to use the **record** argument
As mentioned by Zulan, if I use `SIGINT` instead of `SIGKILL`, I will get an output, but I can get one only if the main process sleeps for 1 second.

Comment: You should edit your question with the result you get with your code. Seems a legitimate question though, don't see why it got downvoted

Comment: Thanks @Mean-Street , will do so !

Comment: You can further improve your question by making sure the code is a proper [mcve] (hint: add `#include`s and check for syntax errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send a `SIGINT` instead of a `SIGKILL` in order to allow `perf` to shutdown cleanly and produce a valid output file. The synchronization between the `perf` child process and the main process will still be imperfect - so if the main process doesn't take significant time as in your example, it is easily possible that no output file is generated at all. This also affects the accuracy of collected data. With the setup of using `perf` as a child process rather than vice-versa, you cannot really improve it.

Comment: Thanks @Zulan. There is a difference between SIGINT and SIGKILL in the ouput. But in both ways, I need to make the parent process sleep to get an output. Also when I look at the valid outputs, the metrics aren't right. Do you think of another way of profiling my main process ?

Comment: As I said, your main process must take some time between `start` and `stop` such that `perf` is even properly initialized. Usually you do it the other way around `perf script ./example`  runs your program as a child - which is much easier to get right in terms of timing. Is there a reason you do not do it that way?

Comment: I am trying to profile only a part of the code. But you're right in my example it is the entire program so it is equivalent to the other way.

Comment: A `usleep(1000)` after `start` and `stop` wouldn't be the worst idea for a pragmatic solution with `perf`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that perf attaches itself to the process and then waits for process termination to print counters. try adding for example the

```
-I msec
```

option to perf like -I 1000 to print counters every 1s.
changing your args to execvp to

```
char *args[] = {"/usr/bin/perf", "stat", "-p",ppid_str,"-o", filename, "-I", "1000", NULL};
```

and your inc to a loop of something like

```
while (a < 10) {
    a += 1;
    sleep(1);
}
```

while yield results although the file is not properly closed() in this approach. 
I would create a small binary that execs perf with a timeout and gracefully closes the file and run that from the child.

Comment: Thanks @ramrunner, it is working in your example. The issue with _-I_ is it depends on the command **stat**. I may use  **record**. Also, I don't want to add that much overhead in my program if for example the interval is too small. If it is too long, I will have an empty output.

Comment: sure, i don't disagree with you , or say this is the correct way to get metrics from your process, i just thought to answer the question of why you don't get any output ;). good luck with your profiling.